# First Approach with Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

this is my first approach with scala language, so sorry for the question (maybe trivial)
I run this sample code (In a subsistem Ubuntu on Windows10), but I have a doubt: why in my console a saw first test2 and then test?
Thanks

```
object MyModule {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    println("test")
    println("test2")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to wrap `main` body into curly braces:

```
object MyModule {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("test")
        println("test2")
    }
}
```

You can omit them only if the implementation is just one line.
By the way you did not define a module but an object, which is essentially a singleton class with static methods only.

ps: the reason for which you see both logs is that, the `println("test2")` is interpreted as if it was in the `MyModule` constructor, then the `main()` gets executed and you see "test" (so your code is actually valid, but only the first line is consider as part of the main implementation)